# IIS application pool identity doesn't respect Windows security

Tags: security, iis, windows-server-2012, application-pools

I am using Windows 2012 and have configured my IIS application pool to use my own '**XXXWeb**' account. My website is using the correct application pool (the W3WP process is also running as 'XXXWeb'). I configured the 'XXXWeb' user that it doesn't have write permissions in the web directory.

To my surprise, I saw that the user could write a logfile in a directory where the 'XXXWeb' user doesn't have any rights. I checked using Process Monitor and I saw that the 'WriteFile' operation was executed with 'XXXWeb' privilege and it succeeded. When I try to write the exact same file when I logged on as 'XXXWeb' it fails.

Does anyone know what could be wrong? I don't want the AppPool to have write rights to prevent security issues, when my IIS is getting hacked for some reason.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue on win 2008.   Under authentication, Anonymous Authentication for the website, it was set to IUsr.  Maybe try changing that to App Pool Identity.